# Does anyone know if we can start a storedprocedure in Aurora based on SQS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-aurora

I am trying to export data from Aurora into S3, I have created a stored procedure to perform this action. I can schedule this on the Aurora Scheduler to run at a particular point in time.

However, I have multiple tables - could go up to 100; so I want my process controller which is a python script sitting in Lambda to send a Queue Message - Based on this Queue message the stored procedure in Aurora will be started

I am looking at this for the following reasons

- I do not want too much time lag between starting two exports
- I also do not want two exports overlapping in execution time

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any built-in integration that allows SQS to interact with Aurora.

Obviously you can do this externally, with a queue consumer that reads from the queue and invokes the procedures, but that doesn't appear to be relevant, here.

Comment: you are right - that will be another python program unless we have functions in Aurora to listen to SQS - does anyone know if they exist

Comment: They don't exist.  As I indicated, there isn't any built-in integration... and Aurora does not allow you to add user-defined functions (which can interact with the outside world and are written in C/C++, and are not to be confused with stored functions, which are written in SQL and are of course supported but of no help, here).

Comment: That was my guess too. Wanted to post and see if anyone has done something similar they could share

Answer (score 0):

I have used lambda with alembic package to create schema and structures. I know we could create users and execute other database commands - the same way execute a stored procedure

Lambda could prove to be expensive - we probably could have an container to do it

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you are trying to export data from Aurora into S3 at some schedule.
I would recommend you to use [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) service.
This is the proper way to solve this kind of problem.

> AWS Data Pipeline is a web service that helps you reliably process and move data between different AWS compute and storage services, as well as on-premises data sources, at specified intervals. With AWS Data Pipeline, you can regularly access your data where it’s stored, transform and process it at scale, and efficiently transfer the results to AWS services such as Amazon S3, Amazon RDS, Amazon DynamoDB, and Amazon EMR.